# iPhone, hook for edit/done button click in table view

Tags: iphone, uitableview

In my table view controller there is

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

which produces a regular edit/done button at the top left corner. Hence, once the user clicks "Edit", the button caption changes to "Done" and the table entries may be deleted or reordered. I would like to get notified once the user actually clicks "Done". Is there a hook for that?

Background: I'd like to persist the order of the entries i.e. next time the user pulls up this view I'd like to present the entries in the least recently used order.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

for those who are still interesed in this question (or answer :P)

[UITableView API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/setEditing:animated:)

revealed that there is a `- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animate` method
these method is called every time this edit/done button is pressed. you have to simply check by the `(BOOL)editing` parameter wich one was used. last but not least you have to call the proper method from the originally edit/done button.

simply add this method to your uitableview class

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animate
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animate];
    if(editing)
    {
        NSLog(@"editMode on");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Done leave editmode");
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that setEditing:animated() also gets called if anything programmatically puts the view in edit mode.  I added an additional method that only calls [super setEditing] that I can use to externally set the editing mode.

Comment: Note: If you're doing this through a `UIViewController` as a `UITableView` **delegate**, make sure to tell the `UITableView` to set the **table's** editing status with `[self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated]`.

Answer (score 3):

For those who don't want to override UITableView (e.g. if you're using UITableViewController), here's a simple and clean solution that I use. It basically involves creating your own edit button item and using the tableView's `editing` flag to track edit vs done. For icing on the cake, it shows a "+" button (instead of "Edit") when the table is empty for adding new items.

```
- (void) updateEditButtonVisibility
{
    // tableItems represents the data structure that s
    if ([tableItems count] > 0)
    {
        UIBarButtonSystemItem editButtonType = self.tableView.editing ? UIBarButtonSystemItemDone : UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit;
        UIBarButtonItem *editButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:editButtonType
                                                                                        target:self
                                                                                        action:@selector(editButtonTouched)];

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButtonItem;
        [editButtonItem release];
    }
    else
    {
        UIBarButtonItem *addButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                                                                       target:self
                                                                                       action:@selector(addButtonTouched)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButtonItem;
        [addButtonItem release];
    }
}

- (void) editButtonTouched
{
    // edit/done button has been touched

    [self.tableView setEditing:!self.tableView.editing animated:YES];
    [self updateEditButtonVisibility];
}

- (void) addButtonTouched
{
    // logic to allow user to add new items goes here
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self updateEditButtonVisibility];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the standard way to get notified when a bar button has been pushed:

```
self.editButtonItem.target = self;
self.editButtonItem.action = @selector(buttonPushed:);

...

- (void) buttonPushed:(id)sender
{
// do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Well, I know that. The point is that I don't want to interfere with what the button already does (modify list entries, toggle its caption, etc.). I simply would like to know when it is clicked in its "Done" state.

Comment: UIBarButtonItems don't derive from UIControl so you can't just add another target to it. You can always capture the action and maintain the state yourself. It's not that hard. Or else, get the buttonPushed call (above) then set an 'ignore' flag and turn around and synthesize a one-time event back at the button to let it do its thing. Details on synthesizing touch events here: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/synthesizing-touch-event-on-iphone.html

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change the action. After edit button clicked it shows delete button, instead it is possible to show reject/verify/modify buttons. And change corresponding action instead of delete option

Thanks
Mindus